# PHP explode on any characters in given array

Tags: php, arrays, explode

Is there any way I can designate a string delimiter as being any character from an array?
For example:

```
 $delimiter = range("a","z");
 $str = "103a765g678d6f76h";
 $newstr = $explode($delimiter, $str);
```

Resulting in `$newstr` being `[103,765,678,6,76]`

I couldn't find anything on google on how to do this nor could I think of anything myself

Comment: i don't think preg_split is very necessary for this tbh, but use what is best for you bud.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) and a regular expression to achieve what you want.

The `implode()` is only neccessary if you must `range()` your desired characters in an array first, it simply concatenates the array elements together to make a string.

```
$delimiter = range("a","z");

$chars = implode($delimiter);
$str = "103a765g678d6f76h";
$newstr = preg_split("/[$chars]+/", $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/208464)

Comment: Thanks, this solves my problem in a single line!

Comment: @Bobdinator Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
function multiexplode ($delimiters,$string) {

    $ready = str_replace($delimiters, $delimiters[0], $string);
    $launch = explode($delimiters[0], $ready);
    return  $launch;
}
 $delimiter = range("a","z");
     $str = "103a765g678d6f76h";

$text = "here is a sample: this text, and this will be exploded. this also | this one too :)";
$newstr = multiexplode($delimiter ,$str );

print_r($newstr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your data and use preg_replace to replace the range of characters with a single delimiter character. Then explode the modified string.

Answer (score 0):

From the PHP explode page this should work for you very well... Doesn't limit it to letters.

```
function multiexplode ($delimiters,$string) {

    $ready = str_replace($delimiters, $delimiters[0], $string);
    $launch = explode($delimiters[0], $ready);
    return  $launch;
}

$text = "here is a sample: this text, and this will be exploded. this also | this one too :)";
$exploded = multiexplode(array(",",".","|",":"),$text);
```

Delimiters needs to be an array.

Read more [on the PHP site](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php#111307)...

Comment: then you can use range to create the array of delimiters for you so on so forth etc etc.

Answer (score -1):

Yes use:

```
preg_split()

delimiter = range("/a-z/");
 $str = "103a765g678d6f76h";
 $newstr =  preg_split($delimiter, $str);
```

Comment: [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) accepts a regular expression as the `pattern`, not an array...

Comment: Yeah. Change the $delimeter to a regular expression